# (CRON) (No MTA installed, discarding output) &&& pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user roo

Tags: cron

[image]

Kindly help me with above error.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there are no Mail Transfere Agent (MTS) installed in your system. Therefor cron can not mail the standard- and error-out to your user.

Look at installing sendmail, postfix or similar MTA in your system, OR make sure to redirect standard-out and -error from the cron job to a file you can read.

Comment: Could you please guide in deep, how to redirect

Comment: There are lot's of examples in the proposed duplicate ...